# Scaling of Inkscape generated PS tricks tex file in Latex

Tags: pstricks, inkscape

I try to draw a figure in Inkscape (0.91) and then include it in a Latex document using the "LaTex with PSTricks macros" .tex filetype. I use the following code to embed the generated `squintAntsBlockdiagA4.tex` file in latex:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering%
\input{Grafix/squintAntsBlockdiagA4.tex}
\caption{Schematic representation of proposed antenna geometry.}\label{fig:schema}
\end{figure}
```

The output looks nice, but is scaled (smaller) than the figure drawn in Inkscape. When I generate a eps in Inkscape instead, the figure is not scaled and appears as desired.
Is there a way to generate an non-scaled version directly from Inkscape?

Or how can I scale the figure back to the original size without trial and error modifying the `\psset{xunit=.5pt,yunit=.5pt,runit=.5pt}` command in the .tex filegenerated by Inkscape?

Comment: I suppose that you can set the unit in Inkscape. By the way: 0.5pt for the Unit makes absolutely no sense!